# Matlab - averaging matrices stored in cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

Basic question for matlab. I have a cell array (2000*1), where each contains a 4*4 matrix. How can I create the average of the 2000 4*4 matrices. I thought mean( cell arrary, 3) would work, but I recieve this error:

??? Undefined function or method 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Store your matrices as a 4x4x2000 array instead, so you can just say mean(array, 3).  The storage is also more efficient than the cell array, and if you want to loop, just write `array(:,:,ii)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a 4x4 average of all corresponding elements:

```
>> mean( cat(3, myCell{:}), 3 )
```

Comment: Great, thanks. So we stack the 2000 matrices on top of each other and average on the 3rd dim.

Comment: @user2941568 precisely so.

Comment: @user2941568 Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it does what you wanted

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for caring, but I suspect this is a "one time user": wam bam and never to be seen again...

Comment: @Shai Sadly, that happens a lot

Comment: @LuisMendo well, [life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair)...

Comment: @Shai Very interesting! The idea of the long tail is... comforting

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'm still wowed by the flood of upvotes for that [`interp1` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19533488/2778484), as correct as it was (although I upvoted it too). It hit SO less than a minute before I would submit my own nearly identical answer, so I decided to salvage mine by adding a finer point, recognizing it was only supplemental to Shai's. Now, I'm not sure if it's perfect, but it at least mirrors how `imresize` does resampling, so it seemed like a good contribution... time will tell.