# Sum consecutive groups of elements of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Consider the array

```
A = [x1,x2,x3,...,xn]
```

Can you then in an easy way add two consecutive numbers in the array together in Matlab, such that you get:

```
B = [x1+x2, x3+x4,...]
```

Note that the each element only appears in one sum.

Comment: You have a lot of good answers here.  Pay it forward and accept one of the answers here as per @thewaywewalk described.  Please and thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `sum` and `reshape` -

```
B = sum(reshape(A,2,[]),1)
```

---

With `interp1` based on [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533488/3293881) -

```
nA = numel(A);
start = 1/(2*nA-2);
stop = 1 - start;
B = 2*interp1( linspace(0,1,nA), A,linspace(start,stop,nA/2))
```

---

If playing [`code-golf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), [`vec2mat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) from `Communications System Toolbox` could be used -

```
B = sum(vec2mat(A,2),2)
```

Or even more compact -

```
B = sum(vec2mat(A,2)')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
B = A(1:2:end)+A(2:2:end)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
B = A(1:2:end) + A(2:2:end);
```

Best,

Answer (score 4):

In case numel(A) is not always even:

```
accumarray(ceil([1:numel(A)]'/2),A(:))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other approaches for generic group sizes:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
groupsize = 2;
```

## Approach 1

```
B = filter( ones(groupsize,1), 1, A )
B = B(groupsize:groupsize:end)
```

---

```
B = 3 7 11 15
```

## Approach 2

```
B = conv(A,ones(groupsize,1))
B = B(groupsize:groupsize:end)
```

---

```
B = 3 7 11 15 9
```

Advantage over [**Divakar's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264860/2605073), [**Ratberts's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264848/2605073) and [**Jolek's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264847/2605073) **solution** is that it also works for vectors `A` which are not dividable by the group size. Be aware that both my approaches deal slightly different for the last element in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that A has an even number of elements (xn is even), here one solution:

- Extract odd elements to a sub-array called odd_arr
- Extract even elements to a sub-array called even_arr
- Add the two sub-arrays together to make B

Here is the Matlab code (Long Version):

```
    odd_arr  = A(1:2:end);
    even_arr = A(2:2:end);
    B        = odd_arr + even_arr;
```

Here is the short version:

```
    B = A(1:2:end) + A(2:2:end);
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different from Ratbert's and jojek's answer.

Comment: It's very interesting. Apparently while writing my answer, Ratbert and jojek had come up with the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
     B = downsample(A + [A(2:end), 0], 2)
```

Comment: Warning: `downsample` is only available in the Signal Processing toolbox.  This code can't be run without it.